# How to use pagedlistpager when passing a viewmodel to my action

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

What do I use for my second parameter to '@Html.PagedListPager'?
If I have a action in my controller that accepts a viewmodel like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Search(HomePageViewModel viewModel) 
    {
        var pagedList = repository.GetYogaList(viewModel.SearchQuery, viewmodel.Date)
        viewModel.YogaList = pagedList;
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_mySpaces", viewModel);
        }

        return View(viewModel);
     }
```

and a partial page containing the paged list html helper

here is the partial '_mySpaces.html'

```html
@model HomePageViewModel
<div id="yogaSpaceList">

  <div class="pagedList">
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model.YogaSpaces, page => Url.Action("Search", new { Model }), PagedListRenderOptions.MinimalWithItemCountText)
  </div>

  @foreach (var space in Model.YogaSpaces) {
  <div>
    <h4>@space.Overview.Title</h4>
    <div>
      @space.Overview.Summary
    </div>
  </div>
  }
</div>
```

Comment: You don't pass your model, you pass a value (`int`) indicating the page to display. And it should be a GET, not a POST method. Look at the examples on the [PagedList site](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList)

Comment: if Search is my main action used to first run my search query from my home page and I'm passing in a viewmodel, should I create a new action for the paging? the thing I'm a little confused about is, I have to pass in some viewmodel data to the action, like search query, date, etc, etc. So I need that viewmodel data in addition to the page.

Comment: Something like `@Html.PagedListPager( Model.YogaSpaces, page => Url.Action("Search", new { page = page, searchText = someValue, date = anotherValue, etc }) )` and then add those parameters to your GET method

Comment: so I can't use my action "Search" that passes in a viewmodel?

Comment: It does not make sense to do so. Your method should be a GET, not a POST and you cant pass a complex object containing a collection property to a GET method (binding will fail). And you need to pass is the page number anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Ok you can pass a viewmodel back to an action but as previously state it needs to be a GET method so mark your action with the HttpGet attribute. The MVC framework will translate/bind the query string to your view model.

Your controller should look something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search(ViewModel viewModel) 
{
    \\ do something useful here and return ActionResult .....
}
```

You will need to add a page property to your ViewModel and a method allows your .cshtml code to set the page number and returns the viewmodel as an object. MVC will translate the object into a query string for the action link.

```
Public class ViewModel {

    // other properties and stuff

    public int? Page { get; set; }
    public object ToPagedListParameters(int page)
    {
         this.Page = page;
         return this;
    }
}
```

Then all that is need is a small adjustment to your .cshtml file

```html
<div class="pagedList">
      @Html.PagedListPager(viewModel, page => Url.Action("Search",viewModel.ToPagedListParameters(page))
</div>
```

**Note:** I have only got this working with simple viewModels and have not tried it with viewModels that contain collections or lists.